# QDialogButtonBox: Set button width

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to set the size of buttons in a `QDialogButtonBox`, but apparently, this won't work:

```
foreach(QAbstractButton *p, ui_->buttonBox->buttons())
{
    QPushButton *q = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(p);

    QRect r = q->geometry();

    r.setWidth(max * 2);

    q->setGeometry(r);
}
```

Do you know if I can set a uniform size of all buttons?

Comment: I think these buttons are placed in layout, and setting geometries will not help much. You can try to set the minimum and maximum sizes of each button. Just curious, why do you need it?

Comment: @vahancho setting the minimum width works, thanks! Why I want that? Well, probably for just aesthetics, nothing more :) I can't stand different sizes, it's a problem I recognize that!